# Preventing a user from entering anything but integers into a textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am constructing a form in Access and I have several textboxes that require an integer value. Right now you can enter characters instead of number and a debugging window pops up when the submit button is pressed. How can I prevent users from being able to press the submit button when an invalid entry is made in the interger textbox.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried putting the 'check-for-number' code in a `_BeforeUpdate` or `OnChange` event of the text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make the field a Number type in the table design. Then go down to the "Field properties" and make sure "Field size" is set to Integer. This takes care of decimal numbers because it will round them to the nearest integer when the textbox loses focus.

Next, go into the submit button properties and set Enabled = False. This will gray it out and won't allow the user to click it. You may want to add this code to the form's On Current property so that whenever a record is loaded, it will enable or disable the submit button based on the value that is already there. You will need to "AND" in more integer textbox objects to the same if statement if you have more than one integer textbox on your form:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Not IsNumeric(Me.IntegerTextBox.Value) Then
        Me.SubmitButton.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.SubmitButton.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, add this code to the On Change event for the textbox. This will enable the button whenever an appropriate a numeric value has been entered and will update the button every time a key is pressed.

```
Private Sub IntegerTextBox_Change()
    If Not IsNumeric(Me.IntegerTextBox.Text) Then
        Me.SubmitButton.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.SubmitButton.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Do this for each integer field on your form.

Comment: Just wanted to know if this was the answer you were looking for or not?

Comment: Is there any way I can use this code and still allow decimals? But I think this is the right direction I need to go in

Comment: Yes. Go into your table design and make the field type Number. Then go down to the field properties and change the property "Field size" from Integer to Single (or Double if you have large decimals). I will leave the posted answer as Integer since that was your original question.

Comment: @BriannaCates Also, see the other step I added for the form's On Current event.

Comment: One more question if there are textboxes linked to the submit button that do no require a number value but just text how can I have the submit button turn back on when any input is put into these boxes

Comment: Nevermind I just used the same code with If Null.. Thanks so much

Comment: Actually I do have one more question can you use this code with a checkbox to allow the button to be enabled when the box has been checked?

Answer (score 0):

In table Design make the data Type Number (Integer).